# Jquery FancyBox target specific DIV ID?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How do I get Fancy box to target a specific DIV ID on a page and not request the whole page in the fancybox.?
This my code so fare

```
$(function() {

$(".style_image a").live('click', function(event) { 

    $(".style_image a").find("#show_style").fancybox();       

});
});
```

This don't work?

I originally tried the following:

```
 $(function() {

    $(".style_image a").live('click', function(event) { 

        $(this.href + " #show_style").fancybox();       

    });
    });
```

Not sure how this done, or if it is even possible?

[here are the doc's](http://fancybox.net/howto)

Answer (score 24):

If you want fancybox to open a certain div you just use the following simple steps:

First you need a link to hook FancyBox to:

```
<a href="#myDivID" id="fancyBoxLink">Click me to show this awesome div</a>
```

Note the **div id** next to the anchor.

Second you need a div that will be shown inside the FancyBox:

```
<!-- Wrap it inside a hidden div so it won't show on load -->
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="myDivID">
         <span>Hey this is what is shown inside fancybox.</span>
         <span>Apparently I can show all kinds of stuff here!</span>
         <img src="../images/unicorn.png" alt="" />
         <input type="text" value="Add some text here" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And third some very easy javascript to hook it all together

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a#fancyBoxLink").fancybox({
        'href'   : '#myDivID',
        'titleShow'  : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How about using an ID to open the div in a fancybox if you can't change the href value? i.e. open a div in a fancybox when clicking on an img that has an ID>

Comment: If I understood well this example, it's very complicated with 100 images because I need to write 100 scripts, each for one image because it works with ID.
Also, my aim was to open fancy image in a div which is cca. 70% of the screen width but with this method, when I open the image, it is opening in 100% screen size, just like originally...

Answer (score 7):

You just need this selector:

```
$("#show_style").fancybox();
```

The [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (since IDs should be unique) is just `#IDGoesHere`

I *think* what you're after is loading the content in some fancybox, if you want to load say `<div id="content"></div>` from the page the href points to, you'd do this using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(".style_image a").on('click', function(event) { 
  $('#show_style').load(this.href + " #content").fancybox();       
});
```

`.load()` has an option for `url selector` that loads only part of the destination page.