# Fancybox v2.1.3

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi to all fancybox lovers. How do i insert helpers here:

```
     $(document).mouseleave(function() {
         $.fancybox("#feedback_form");
     });​
```

I 've got stuck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I guess) you can do:

```
     $(document).mouseleave(function() {
         var options = {
           openEffect: 'elastic',
           helpers: {
             title: {
               type: 'inside'
             }
           }
         };
         $.fancybox("#feedback_form", options);
     });​
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear, but my guess is that you are looking for something like this?

```
 $(document).mouseleave(function() {
         $("#feedback_form").show(); // this will remove the 'display:none'
         $("#feedback_form").fancybox();
 });​
```

Comment: Ok you are right html is:                                           <div style="display:none;" id="feedback_form">
    <form>the form here</form>
</div> that you wrote does not make the form to appear.

Comment: Your div has display set to none. So you'd have to switch that as well. See my updated code.

Comment: Unfortunately this brought to life only "the form here" words with no fancybox effect.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your fancybox setup. Check if the script and the css is loaded correctly.

Comment: Thank you but it seems everything is in place.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613025/jquery-fancybox-target-specific-div-id

Comment: Could you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553308/fancybox-v2-1-3-ajax-load-form/13554178#13554178 ?