# Fancybox v2.1.3 ajax load form

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi again to all fancybox lovers. I got stuck with ajax load an external html form into current  viewed html file. I use a hidden trigger with class="fancybox.ajax" in a tag that is brought into html that way:

```
$('body').prepend('<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="form.html" style="display: none;"></a>');
```

so that form can be brought next with following into html:

```
$(".fancybox.ajax").trigger('click');
```

But this fails. Maybe i need "on" or "live". I do not know if there is a better way to achieve this. Then i want to make some js checks over form submission but how this will run? Maybe some good use of "on"

```
 $('#submit').on(click, function({ .... }));
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather try

```
$(".fancybox").trigger('click');
```

... the class `fancybox` is used to bind such selector to fancybox while the `fancybox.ajax` class is used to define the type of content (you don't need to use `live` since fancybox v2.x already uses that method)

On the other hand, if you want to perform some actions on form submit, try binding the `.on()` method to the `form` selector (not the `submit` button) like

```
$('#formSelector').on("submit", function({ //do somthing }));
```

Comment: Ajax works ok thanks for your answer before but the form then is not processed. My form is <form id="form">Data</form> and my js    $('#form').on("submit", function(){ 
   alert('clicked');
}); but still nothing happens form popup just fails and closes same with $('#submit').click(function(){ ... });

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer to submit the form that is brought with ajax is only

```
$("#submit").live('click', function() { ... });
```

till now, i could not make on() to work by no means.

Comment: is this your own answer? if not, make an update to you question. To make `.on()` to work you need jQuery 1.7+. Is `#submit` the ID of your form? otherwise use `$("#form").on("submit",function(){});`

Comment: Above its my own answer. I use jQuery version 1.8.2, `#submit` is the id of the submit button and `#form` form's id. This `$("#form").on("submit",function(){});` does not work. This `$("#submit").live('click', function() { ... });` works.

Comment: Just FYI `live` is deprecated, `on` should be used instead. Check http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more

Comment: I know but i cannot make this happen with on(). Thanks you very much.