# jQuery and fancybox with click event

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I just want to know if it is possible to create a fancybox, with the content of a hidden div, on a click event. Like this When button is pressed:

```
<input type="button" class="headerButtonNormal" id="test" value="Contact information" onmouseover=this.className="headerButtonHoover"
           onmouseout=this.className="headerButtonNormal" onclick="showFormInformation()">
```

Execute this javascript code and somehow generate a fancybox:

```
function showFormInformation()
{

}
```

And this is the div I want to show:

```
<div id="inline">
Test fancybox
</div>
```

While searching on the internet, it seemed like fancybox isnt made for this... it is more made for link klicking. Should I use a different framework???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right in Fancybox's wheelhouse!

just do:

```
$.fancybox({
    content: $('#inline')
})
```

or as JFK pointed out:

```
$.fancybox({
    href: '#inline'
})
```

you should note that the css path of your hidden div will be different once it is inside your fancybox.

Check out this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819374/599075 ) for another approach!

Comment: ... or better `$.fancybox({href: "#inline"});`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="headerButtonNormal" id="test" value="Contact information"
onmouseover=this.className="headerButtonHoover" onmouseout=this.className="headerButtonNormal">
<div id="inline">Test fancybox</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#test").on("click", function () {
    showFormInformation();

    return false;
});

function showFormInformation() {
    $.fancybox({
        content: $("#inline").html()
    });
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ne4s/)

You might want to move your inline event handlers to be bound using jQuery since you are already using the library.

Comment: ... or better `$.fancybox({href: "#inline"});`